# MYSQLI Select Distinct not working correctly

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I'm using MYSQLI prepared statement to select the distinct data between two tables, however its not outputting at all. Nothing useful in var_dump either. The query works fine in Mysql workbench query.

```html
<?php
include("config.php"); //include config file

if($_POST)
{
 //sanitize post value
 $group_number = filter_var($_POST["group_no"], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT, FILTER_FLAG_STRIP_HIGH);
 
 //throw HTTP error if group number is not valid
 if(!is_numeric($group_number)){
  header('HTTP/1.1 500 Invalid number!');
  exit();
 }
 
 //get current starting point of records
 $position = ($group_number * $items_per_group);
 
 
 //Limit our results within a specified range. 
 $results = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT DISTINCT users.id, users.firstname, users.lastname, 
    media.date, media.time, media.text, media.userID, 
    media.author_id, media.ip, media.post_id, media.format, media.visable,
    media.file_format, media.MediaTxt, media.author_firstname, 
    media.author_lastname, media.shared, media.relation
FROM users 
JOIN media 
    ON (users.id = media.userID)
LEFT JOIN friends
    ON users.id IN (friends.sender, friends.recipient)
WHERE '334' IN (users.id, friends.sender, friends.recipient)
    AND media.relation = 'feed'
AND friends.status = 1
AND media.visable IS NULL
    ORDER BY media.id ASC LIMIT $position, $items_per_group");
     var_dump($results);

 $results->execute(); //Execute prepared Query
 var_dump($results);
 $results->bind_result($results->id, $results->MediaTxt, $results->post_id, $results->userID, $results->firstname, $results->lastname, $results->date, $results->time, $results->text, $results->author_id, $results->ip, $results->format, $results->visable, $results->file_format, $results->author_firstname, $results->author_lastname, $results->shared, $results->relation); //bind variables to prepared statement
 var_dump($results);

 echo '<ul class="page_result">';
 while($results->fetch()){ //fetch values
  echo '<li id="item_'.$results->id.'"><span class="page_name">'.$results->id.') '.$results->post_id.'</span><span class="page_message">'.$results->MediaTxt.'</span></li>'; 
 }
 echo '</ul>';

 $mysqli->close();
}
?>
```

Comment: What does "not outputting at all" mean?

Comment: do proper error checking. mysqli returns boolean false on failure, you're just assuming nothing could ever go wrong. even if the prepare works, there's a near infinite number of reasons why the actual ->execute() will fail.

Comment: I tried that, and its not giving anything I can work on. Is there anything wrong with the echo statement in the while loop?

Comment: yes. you bound to variables. `$results->id` doesn't exist, but `$id` does., ditt for the other two vars. most like you're running with display_errors/error_reporting off, or you'd have been told about using/accessing undefined object members.

Comment: Thats still not helping me, it would be great if you could point out exactly what is wrong with my script so I can see where im going wrong

Comment: I've also updated the post